# Blocking and simultaneously releasing a variable number of threads in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm building a buffer in Java that will collect write actions requested by many threads, and flush them as a group, say, once per second.  I'd like to give it a method called `waitForFlush` that will block and thread that calls it until the next flush event completes.  Meanwhile, a separate, standalone thread is flushing and sleeping in a loop.  So I'm basically looking for a concurrency structure or pattern that will allow many threads to block at a particular point, and then release them all simultaneously, and I'm finding that none of Java's builtin concurrency primitives are a really close match for this.  The best I've come up with so far is wait/notifyAll, as follows:

```
public class Buffer {

  private volatile long lastFlushTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  private final Object flushMonitor = new Object();

  public void waitForFlush() {
    long entryTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    synchronized(flushMonitor) {
      while(lastFlushTime <= entryTime) {
        flushMonitor.wait();
      }
    }
  }

  public void flush() {
    // do flush stuff here
    synchronized(flushMonitor) {
      lastFlushTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      flushMonitor.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Although I think this would work fine in practice, the synchronization block in `waitForNotify()` still feels somewhat imperfect to me.  Ideally, for this use case, you would be able to call `wait()` without synchronizing on the associated Object, and all of the blocked threads would be released at the precise same moment when `notifyAll()` is called, instead of having to exit the synchronized block one-by-one.

So, in general, is there a better way to block and simultaneously release a variable number of threads than I've outlined above (the Semaphore and CountDownLatch classes would only work for for a fixed number of threads,  I think)?

Comment: `instead of having to exit the synchronized block one-by-one` why is this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though a CountDownLatch would work for a one time case as Marko Topolnik and munyengm mention.  It fails in a cyclic scenario (that is you can only `await` & `countDown` once per CDL).  Then you may consider a CyclicBarrier, but that fails in your case because you would need to know the number of threads being used.

If you can use Java 7 I recommend [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).  You can have single thread signalling to many waiting threads and reuse.

```
final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);//register one thread to arrive

 public void waitForFlush() {
    int phase = phaser.getPhase();
    phaser.awaitAdvance(phase);    
 }

  public void flush() {
      lastFlushTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      phaser.arrive(); //signals all waiting threads on the current phase and will increment the phase by 1
  }
```

Comment: Does that mean that `phase` continues to grow unbounded? Won't it overflow eventually? If a CDL is used, it's not such a big deal to replace it with a new one.

Comment: Neat- this solution would let me avoid `System.currentTimeMillis` entirely and just use the phase number, which seems cleaner, in that I didn't actually care when the flush occurred, just that it occurred after some other time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It can reach `Integer.MAX_VALUE` but will not overflow.  Instead it will reset to 0, per JavaDoc `The phase number starts at zero, and advances when all parties arrive at the phaser, wrapping around to zero after reaching Integer.MAX_VALUE.`

Comment: @gsteff You may want to continue with a timestamp as explained in my above comment.

Comment: That's great, didn't know that. I'll keep it in mind for my tasks, too -- once Java 7 comes to the Mac :)

Comment: Why would I still need a timestamp?  According to the Javadocs for `awaitAdvance`, it waits until the phase is not equal to the given phase... so it's doing a not-equal check, not a greater-than check.  Thus, wraparound shouldn't break anything, if that's what you're referring to, right?

Comment: @gsteff Oh I guess if you have a previous `int phaseNumber` and your logic would be if(phaser.getPhase()!=phaseNumber){..} then you should be fine.  I was under the impression you needed a greater than logic.  And yes that is what I was referring to, thanks for clarifying :).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `CountDownLatch` properly, I think it can do it for you. The way is to make your variable number of threads `await` on the latch, and the flushing thread calls `countDown`. The latch is always initialized to 1. This is how it would work:

```
public class FlushControl
{
  private volatile CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  public void awaitFlush() throws InterruptedException { latch.await(); }

  public void flush() {
    final CountDownLatch l = latch;
    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    l.countDown();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that, to release the latch, I'd call `countDown` in a loop until the `getCount()` returns 0?

Comment: You initialize it to 1 and then a single `countDown` releases it. `await` DOES NOT INCREMENT the latch. In fact, NOTHING ever increments the countdown latch.